# SAML integration with APIM 1.9.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have a task to configure WSO2 with SSO with SAML2. When a user accesses the WSO2 products, they will be re-directed to an external Identity Provider. That external provider will then request the user's PKI cert, validate the cert and then send a SAML2 token back to WSO2. At this point, the user would be denied/granted access to the WSO2 products.

Can WSO2 APIM ingest a SAML 2.0 token without having the WSO2 Identity Server?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for you to use an external Identity provider other than the wso2 Identity Server? Also, do you mind mentioning which identity provider you are planning on using? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This should be possible. However, it is required the external Identity provider to support SAML2 standards. You can refer to the WSO2 documentation at [1] on how to set this up with WSO2 Identity Server to get an idea. Depending on your external IDP some of this config (on IDP side) may differ.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Configuring+Single+Sign-on+with+SAML2

Cheers,
Pubudu.

Comment: ok, thanks for your response Pubudu. When the SAML is returned to wso2, where should it be sent? What URL, port, etc.? What type of information should be provided to the IDP in order for them to integrate with wso2?